# Does Libre Office have an equivalent of OneNote, or is there another alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice

I know that LibreOffice is a bit like Microsoft Office, but I can't find the equivalent of OneNote, something that I used a lot before I moved over to Ubuntu, and I do miss the features that it had. Currently I use Evernote Web, or just nothing at all.

Does this not exist?

Comment: Close-voters: Too broad *usually* suggests there are virtually unlimited *different* possible answers or that a satisfactory answer would have to be *extremely* long. Neither applies here. *Maybe* the OneNote part of the question should be split off from the main what's-in-libreoffice question, but since there are no comments to that effect, I don't want to assume that's the reason for the close votes. *I suspect that if this is closed as too broad, it will get five reopen votes shortly thereafter.* Someone who thinks this really should be and stay closed should perhaps comment to explain why.

Comment: IMHO Tim you should just change title to something like "Is there an equivalent for OneNote?" or similar. As a matter of fact, only the title is too broad, the question itself is pretty clear.

Comment: I completely agree with @EliahKagan. How is this broad? It's a very concise question. What are the LibreOffice components -- there not that many -- and what are their Microsoft equivalents. And is one of the LibreOffice components equivalent to OneNote. +1 for the question, and I hope it gets reopened :)

Comment: There are several other software that you can use. Look at [these alternatives][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19230/microsoft-onenote-alternative

Comment: @Unique Thanks for the comment, and welcome to the site! I'd seen that post before, but thanks for the comment. Just a note - comments aren't multi line so to link you have to use this form: `[text](http://example.com) `. It looks like a normal link: [text](http://example.com)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Libreoffice does not have an equivalent to Onenote, but nobody says you should use only Libreoffice on your PC. Along with some of the very good alternatives already pointed out by Sardinha 94410 and muru, you may want to use a program with sync capabilities. In that case you should keep in mind that:

- Evernote works great for taking notes and syncing across devices, and there are two clients which run on Ubuntu ([NixNote](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nevernote/) and [Everpad](https://github.com/nvbn/everpad))
- There is a free [online version of OneNote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/online/) which you can use with a Live account

I personally prefer using the Evernote web interface, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Yeah, I already use Evernote in wine. I actually prefer it to One Note, but one note still has it's uses! I really like the look of that on-line version, especially for my W8 machine, because I refuse to pay for MSO! This has been accepted I really like that, thanks!

Answer (score 38):

#### LibreOffice Start page

This doesn't exist in Microsoft office. From here you can:

- Launch any of the 6 Office programs (create a new document).
- Open a recent file, from the grid of recent files.
- Open any file on your computer, from the Open File button.
- Edit your templates.
- Access Help and the Extensions webpage.

[image: LibreOffice Start page]

---

#### LibreOffice Writer

LibreOffice Writer is the equivalent of MS Word. It has all of the basic functions, like Font, Text size, Alignment, and drawing functions, like Rectangles, Circles and various shapes, like Stars, Call outs (Speech Bubbles) and Arrows.

It can be launched with the command `libreoffice --writer` (creates a new document), searching the dash for "Writer", or clicking its icon on the launcher.

Here is the icon, and a cropped screenshot of the Writer window:

[image: LibreOffice Writer]

As you can see, in the top bar is the standard tool bars, *File*, *Edit*, etc. and the formatting tool bar - *Font* + *Size*, *Colour*, etc.

In the bottom, there is the `Shapes` toolbar with the `Arrows` etc.

---

#### LibreOffice Calc

LibreOffice Calc is the equivalent of MS Excel. It has all of the basic functions, like *Font*, *Text size*, *Alignment*, and some more advanced ones, like *Formula* insertion, *Charts*, *Cell Colouring* and *Conditional Formatting*.

It can be launched with the command `libreoffice --calc` (creates a new document), searching the dash for "Calc" (often Calculator is the first result), or clicking its icon on the launcher.

Here is the icon, and a cropped screenshot of the Calc window:

[image: LibreOffice Calc]

As you can see, in the top bar is the standard tool bars, *File*, *Edit*, etc., and the formatting toolbar - *Font* + *Size*, *Colour*, etc.

At the bottom is the *Find* search bar. This can be focused with the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> shortcut.

---

#### LibreOffice Impress

Libre Office Impress is the equivalent of MS Power Point. It has all of the basic functions, like *Font*, *Text size*, *Alignment*, and others exclusive to Impress, like *Custom Animation*, different Slide views and default text boxes for tiles that come with the templates.

It can be launched with the command `libreoffice --impress` (Creates a new document), searching the dash for "Impress", or clicking its icon on the launcher.

Here is the icon, and a cropped screenshot of the Draw window:

[image: LibreOffice Impress]

As you can see, in the top bar is the standard tool bars, *File*, *Edit*, etc., and the formatting toolbar. In Impress, it is a bit different, it has the colour and line settings for shapes you make. This changes to text when you are typing.

At the bottom is the Shapes tool bar. It has all the shapes that Writer has, but also some extras, like certain freehand shapes, more like Draw (below).

Along the side are the tools exclusive to Impress, like *Custom Animation*, *Master Slides* and *Slide Transitions*.

---

#### LibreOffice Draw

LibreOffice Draw is the equivalent of MS Publisher, a program that doesn't come in the basic MS Office package. It has all of the basic functions, like *Font*, *Text size*, *Alignment*, and others exclusive to Draw, like freehand drawing and better shape manipulation.

It can be launched with the command `libreoffice --draw` (creates a new document), searching the dash for "Draw", or clicking its icon on the launcher.

Here is the icon, and a cropped screenshot of the Draw window:

[image: LibreOffice Draw]

As you can see, in the top bar is the standard tool bars, *File*, *Edit*, etc., and the formatting toolbar. In Draw, it is a bit different, it has the colour and line settings for shapes you make, as text is less often used.

At the bottom is the *Shapes* tool bar. It has all the shapes that Writer has, but also some extras, like certain freehand shapes.

---

#### LibreOffice Math

LibreOffice Math has no equivalent to an MS product. It is very different to all the others, it hasn't got the font tools.

It can be launched with the command `libreoffice --math` (creates a new document), searching the dash for "Math", or clicking its icon on the launcher.

Here is the icon, and a cropped screenshot of the Math window:

[image: LibreOffice Math]

As you can see, in the top bar is the standard tool bars, *File*, *Edit*, etc., but in the standard bar there are unique tools, like *Zoom* and special Greek symbols.

At the bottom is not a toolbar, that is where you enter the formula. The point of Math is to present your formula in a professional way, instead of trying to get `/` and `+` aligned, and formulas over each other.
As an example, it converts this:

```
{π} over { 2 } = sum from { { i = 0 } } to { infinity } { k!} over { (2k +1)!! }
```

to this:

[image: rendered math equation]

---

#### LibreOffice Base

LibreOffice Base is the equivalent of MS Access. It is a very specialised tool, and is designed completely around creating databases.

It can be launched with the command `libreoffice --base` (Creates a new document), searching the dash for "Base", or clicking its icon on the launcher.

Here is the icon, and a cropped screenshot of the Base window:

[image: LibreOffice Base]

As you can see, in the top bar is the standard tool bars, *File*, *Edit*, etc., however in this view most features are disabled, as this is the navigation window, with links to the base wizard.

In the bottom, there is a status bar with details about what you are working on (not included in the screenshot).

---

#### Keyboard shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Copy

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> - Cut

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> - Paste

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> - Undo

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> - Redo

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> - Print

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - Select All

<kbd>F7</kbd> - Spell Check (Check spelling as you type is an option, which I think is enabled by default.)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> - Save

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> - Save as

[A list of general keyboard short cuts](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/General_Shortcut_Keys_in). Here are the specific ones for [Writer](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Shortcut_Keys_for_Writer#Shortcut_Keys_for_LibreOffice_Writer) and [Calc](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Shortcut_Keys_for_Spreadsheets).

---

#### Compatibility

Compatibility with other document types is fairly good. MS Office is not as good at decoding `.odt` documents, but LibreOffice is quite good at saving in that format. Some features (especially formatting of tables, for me) are a bit hit and miss. If compatibility is key, I suggest using the built in export feature to export it to a `.pdf`. Normally however, just saving as a `.doc` or `.docx` is enough for windows users to access it.

They do use different methods to create the same thing, which is why you get issues.

---

#### [The Wiki](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Main_Page)

Most of this came from my memory and experiences. The wiki is:

1. Less biased.
2. More reputable.
3. Has more info, and the info is more accurate.

So I would suggest you have a look in it for information I have (accidentally or purposefully) left out.

---

So, essentially, no, there is no alternative to OneNote built-in; you need to look outside of LibreOffice for this.

Comment: nice one :) 1 thing that might need some emphasis: documents are almost 100% exchangeable between MSO and OO/LO though the 2 might have a different approach to get something done. Biggest difference:MSO uses VBasic, OO/LO uses (mainly) Python.

Comment: @Rinzwind 100% exchangeable in theory, but there're lots of cases when LibO shows MSO documents (`doc`/`docx` in particular) garbled. And MSO sometimes doesn't like ODF docs.

Comment: I thought Draw was analogous to MS Visio

Comment: ** This answer is out-of-date! **

Comment: @Tim The current question is about a OneNote alternative. This answer is about different LibreOffice programs. I do know that this question was originally designed around "What different LO Programs are there?"

Answer (score 16):

#### Give Zim a chance!

I don't fully know MS One Note but maybe you could try `zim`.

> Zim is a graphical text editor used to maintain a collection of wiki pages. Each page can contain links to other pages, simple formatting and images. Pages are stored in a folder structure, like in an outliner, and can have attachments. Creating a new page is as easy as linking to a nonexistent page. All data is stored in plain text files with wiki formatting. Various plugins provide additional functionality, like a task list manager, an equation editor, a tray icon, and support for version control.
>
> [From the Zim webpage](http://zim-wiki.org).

#### My use

I use it as a repository of information I need to use in a daily basis or for some code I need if something goes wrong.

Because it saves the information in TXT files, I put the notes folder in my OwnCloud. So I can read it even I don't have a Zim installed or I'm in another PC. Dropbox or other cloud software that puts a synchronization folder in your filesystem will do.

If you have more than one machine, you could use the same notes in all of them by doing the above.

#### Put your hands on it

It looks like this (A little better in Ubuntu with small icons):

[image: Image of Zim itself]

For more, take a look at [a screencast and screenshots](http://zim-wiki.org/screenshots.html).

You will find it in the [USC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/zim/), in the [download page](http://zim-wiki.org/downloads.html) or by adding the PPA (From the [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~jaap.karssenberg/+archive/ubuntu/zim)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jaap.karssenberg/zim  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install zim
```

**Edit:**

Also interesting is the [Zim Wiki Community Documentation](https://github.com/jaap-karssenberg/zim-wiki/wiki) page at Github.

Comment: That looks good!

Comment: It's so late but just wanted to say I also use it, it's great, but if you want something even more advanced, you can try emacs/spacemacs org-mode.

Answer (score 9):

For OneNote, you might have to look outside LibreOffice. There are a few alternatives, and none that I use, so no recommendations. I think each Desktop Environment (GNOME, KDE, etc.) has their own notes app.

- [Tomboy](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tomboy) - I think this used to be available by default on Ubuntu. This is the GNOME notes app.
- [Gnote](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gnote) - And I think this replaced Tomboy as the default.
- [KNotes](https://apps.kde.org/knotes/) - from KDE.
- [XFCE4 Notes](https://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-notes-plugin/start) - from XFCE4.

In addition, depending on your DE, their might be other options, such as applets for MATE, [extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/568/notes/) for GNOME Shell, [desklets](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/desklets/view/38) for Cinnamon, etc.

Comment: [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/) would probably be a closer equivalent to OneNote.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently started using [cherrytree](https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/). It is exactly what I would look for as an alternative to OneNote. Also other people have good reviews about it on Ubuntu One. You can install it from the Software Center. I have also tried [Zim-wiki](https://zim-wiki.org/), but I am liking cherrytree more.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Springseed, which is a very handy note taking app for Ubuntu and you can sync to your Dropbox account.

Visit the [Springseed Site](http://getspringseed.com/) for more details.

Comment: Normally I'd ask for more info but the page says nothing either!

Comment: You're not missing much.  I just tried it and the application is extremely minimalistic.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in previous posts, LibreOffice doesn't offer something like Microsoft OneNote. I lost a lot of time trying and comparing alternatives and my choice is [Joplin](https://joplinapp.org/). It is an open-source note app with support for Linux/Windows/macOS/Android/iOS and many synchronization options.

Answer (score 0):

There is no LibreOffice version of OneNote that I'm aware of.

I use Obsidian. You can link your office documents into the software and put in images. Utilizing the LibreOffice Draw app, you can add hand-written notes. There are also a good number of useful plugins such as flash cards. Linking notes together and the other organization tools helps me significantly.

[image: Picture of my Obsidian]

https://obsidian.md/

Obsidian is free for private use, but it's not an open source app. I heard good things about Logseq, which is open source.