# Can I run Microsoft Office 2013/2014?

Tags: windows, wine, microsoft-office

Is there a way to run Microsoft Office 2013 or 2014 on Ubuntu 14.04? Wine won't work.

Comment: No, not all software will run with wine.  Sometimes you just cannot run Microsoft software in Linux.  Google search shows that 2013 will not run in wine.  If you absolutely must run software developed for Windows, it is usually best to have windows to guarantee it works the way it should.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Can't you use libre office? http://askubuntu.com/a/511630/186134

Comment: Our solution to this?

Comment: Necessary at Work, important

Comment: see this http://www.howtogeek.com/171565/how-to-install-microsoft-office-on-linux/

Comment: @KasiyA [That tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/171565/how-to-install-microsoft-office-on-linux/) seems to use Office 2007. Will this work with the newer versions of Microsoft Office as well?

Comment: @EliahKagan this link https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=31

Answer (score 2):

As some commentators stated, not all apps can be installed using Wine. If you must have, basically, native Microsoft Office you will have to use their online equivalents. If you're a Chrome person, there are also web app versions of MS Office apps as well.

[Microsoft Office Online](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/online/)

[Chrome Web Store - Word Online](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/word-online/fiombgjlkfpdpkbhfioofeeinbehmajg)

Comment: I know, WINE that does not work!
I am looking for a solution not be WINE!
Online MS Office Wrong!

Comment: Did you read the rest of my post? You should use the web apps. That's the best you can do on Linux.