# Onenote web doesn't work on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, wine, chromium, microsoft-office

I have a desktop with Xubuntu 16.04 (fresh-installed a month ago): Onenote web doesn't work with both Firefox (onenote page remain white forever) and Chromium (it opens the page, but the loading icon on the adress bar keep running and the links on notes are disactive, the coursor doesn't change).

Had anyone the same problem and knows how to fix it? If i have to use another browser, i'll install it.

(I also tried to install the windows app on wine, but setup failed).

Thanks!

Comment: Try [Brave](https://www.brave.com/). Install via `wget -O brave.deb https://laptop-updates.brave.com/latest/dev/ubuntu64` and `sudo dpkg -i ./brave.deb` if you have 64 bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Their site](https://www.onenote.com/) is broken, maybe on purpose *(although the [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) and wide experience with their broken standards, non-conformant hardware, lack of drivers, suggests that MS just lacks good engineers)*. The problem is that it shows empty page for most *(all?)* browsers except of Internet Explorer.

How did I know it? I assumed it because in ancient past existed sites that only worked with Internet Explorer, so I installed [addon to fake user agent](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/developers), made it to look like IE8, and — voilà — site suddenly works!

To solve the problem you have to do the same. Also, I'd highly recommend to create a forum topic about the problem on MS site *(so that the problem was publicly known by MS)*, and, perhaps, send a bug-report to MS support.

MS is known to have bad support for many apps *(skype, drivers, just out off top of my head)*, so I'd also recommend to [check an alternative](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19230/microsoft-onenote-alternative) to One Note *(I can't adice it myself, because I didn't use anything like this, but linked suggestions are highly upvoted, perhaps worth a try; or, at least, leaving a comment what do you miss. And remember, those apps are FOSS, so you can easily find their bugtracker, and create a new "feature request" there.)*.

Comment: I have no words, that was the problem. I have to use ie 6 user agent to log in, then the firefox default one to see my notes (ie 6 is too old). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At least for me, it works to open [the notebook list directly](https://www.onenote.com/notebooks) instead of [just the bare domain](https://www.onenote.com/). This way you might be able to save the extra step for switching between different user agents.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a fairly simple workaround for this. Go to https://onedrive.live.com first, log in there and then open your OneNote documents from there. I was able to do this on Firefox after first getting a blank page when trying to get straight to https://www.onenote.com/. I have Linux Mint 18.1 installed.